# How to Set Style to image pattern on mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Hi i'm creating bus and subway routing using mapbox and react - i need different color for my pattern that drawing line on the map you can see my sample pattern on image below

[look at my pattern image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7tVu.png)

as you can see pattern has static color (green) i need to set this color dynamically with hex code that return from server.

if wrote function for get pattern

```js
 getPattern(type, section_type, index, line_name) {
      

        if (section_type === routingTypes.METRO) {
            switch (line_name) {
            case '1':
                return pattern_metro_1;

            case '2':
                return pattern_metro_1;

            case '3':
                return [pattern_metro_1, '#00B8F8'];

            case '4':
                return '<img src={pattern_metro_1} style="border: 3px solid green" />';

            case '5':
                return pattern_metro_1;

            case '6':
                return pattern_metro_1;

            case '7':
                return pattern_metro_1;

            default:
                return pattern_metro_1;
            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see all cases are static pattern image but i need some thing like case 3 that i set image and pattern and image fill with that color.
also i tried case 4 but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think it fails because you are using ' wrongly,

Try this

```js
case '4':
  return '<img src={pattern_metro_1} style="border: 3px solid green" />';
```

Comment: thanks but No It's not working.  showing this error : mapbox-gl-unminified.js:1356 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load image because of The source image could not be decoded.. Please make sure to use a supported image type such as PNG or JPEG. Note that SVGs are not supported.

Comment: That’s a different error, the syntax errors you had was different, no? What’s the value of pattern_metro_1

Comment: pattern_metro_1 is Image URL

Comment: Being so cryptic and with this level of detail I cannot help you. Good luck!